# Second Monitor No Longer Working - Centos 8

Tags: multi-monitor

I have a two monitors set up - both plugged into an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970. My main monitor using the display port (Acer), the other using an HDMI (Samsung).

Everything was working until I did a system update and now only the main monitor plugged into the display port seems to work.

I've looked into the following:

In GNOME 3 Settings > Devices > Displays. Only my main monitor shows up here. Previously, I could see both monitors.

Output for xrandr -q

```
xrandr -q
xrandr: Output HDMI-0 is not disconnected but has no modes
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 621mm x 341mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  24.00  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I looked into the NVIDIA X Server Settings. In "X Server Display Configuration", I can see the second monitor however when I click on it, it says Configuration: Disabled. I've tried changing the configuration to New X Screen, but this didn't seem to do anything following the X restart. When I try to 'Save to X Configuration File' this is what the preview provides. There is no mention of the Samsung monitor

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 450.80.02

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 450.80.02

Section "ServerLayout"

# Removed Option "Xinerama" "1"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "1"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Acer XB280HK"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 140.0
    VertRefresh     30.0 - 70.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 970"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

When I boot my PC to the Windows side, both monitors work correctly and I've tried unplugging the monitors so I'm fairly confident it's not a connection problem.

Thank you for your help!

Edit Additional Information:

yum history showed:

no nvidia updates

xorg updates

```
    Upgrade  xorg-x11-drv-ati-19.1.0-1.el8.x86_64                                                   @AppStream
    Upgrade  xorg-x11-drv-intel-2.99.917-39.20200205.el8.x86_64                                     @AppStream
    Upgrade  xorg-x11-proto-devel-2020.1-3.el8.noarch                                               @AppStream
    Upgrade  xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.8-6.el8.x86_64                                               @AppStream
    Upgrade  xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.20.8-6.el8.x86_64                                               @AppStream
    Upgrade  xorg-x11-server-Xwayland-1.20.8-6.el8.x86_64                                           @AppStream
    Upgrade  xorg-x11-server-common-1.20.8-6.el8.x86_64                                             @AppStream
    Upgrade  xorg-x11-xkb-utils-7.7-28.el8.x86_64                                                   @AppStream
    Upgraded xorg-x11-drv-ati-19.0.1-2.el8.x86_64                                                   @@System
    Upgraded xorg-x11-drv-intel-2.99.917-38.20180618.el8.x86_64                                     @@System
    Upgraded xorg-x11-proto-devel-2018.4-1.el8.noarch                                               @@System
    Upgraded xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.6-3.el8.x86_64                                               @@System
    Upgraded xorg-x11-server-Xvfb-1.20.6-3.el8.x86_64                                               @@System
    Upgraded xorg-x11-server-Xwayland-1.20.6-3.el8.x86_64                                           @@System
    Upgraded xorg-x11-server-common-1.20.6-3.el8.x86_64                                             @@System
    Upgraded xorg-x11-xkb-utils-7.7-27.el8.x86_64                                                   @@System
```

kernel updates

```
    Install  kernel-4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64                                                     @BaseOS
    Install  kernel-core-4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64                                                @BaseOS
    Install  kernel-devel-4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64                                               @BaseOS
    Install  kernel-modules-4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64                                             @BaseOS
    Upgrade  texlive-l3kernel-7:20180414-19.el8.noarch                                              @AppStream
    Upgrade  kernel-abi-whitelists-4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.noarch                                      @BaseOS
    Upgrade  kernel-headers-4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64                                             @BaseOS
    Upgrade  kernel-tools-4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64                                               @BaseOS
    Upgrade  kernel-tools-libs-4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64                                          @BaseOS
    Upgraded kernel-4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64                                                           @@System
    Upgraded kernel-core-4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64                                                      @@System
    Upgraded kernel-modules-4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64                                                   @@System
    Upgraded texlive-l3kernel-7:20180414-14.el8.noarch                                              @@System
    Upgraded kernel-abi-whitelists-4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2.noarch                                     @@System
    Upgraded kernel-headers-4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2.x86_64                                            @@System
    Upgraded kernel-tools-4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2.x86_64                                              @@System
    Upgraded kernel-tools-libs-4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2.x86_64                                         @@System
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information about your setup? Linux distribution, the versions of xorg/linux kernel/nvidia driver packages that got updated in the upgrade that botched your setup? (the versions that got updated should be available in your apt/yum/pacman history)

Comment: I missed the distro name in question title - in centos 8, you should be able to find out the upgraded packages via `yum history`.

Comment: Thank you @Zaroth, I've edited the post to show selected yum history.